# Stop EF Core from building tables with prefixed names IdentityDbContext

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have my DBContext extending IdentityDbContext however, when looking at the abstract class IdentityDbContext, I see DbSets like 'UserRoles' and 'RoleClaims' etc.

The issue is, when i build the database, the tables come out as 'ASPNetUserRoles' instead of just 'UserRoles'.  Does anyone know how to avoid this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you can see from the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/rel/2.0.0-preview2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/IdentityDbContext.cs#L173), these are hardcoded in the base `IdentityDbContext` fluent configuration.

What you can do is to override `OnModelCreating` (if you haven't yet), call the base implementation and then loop over the model entity types and remove the prefix from the table names.

Something like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        const string TableNamePrefix = "AspNet";
        var tableName = entityType.Relational().TableName;
        if (tableName.StartsWith(TableNamePrefix))
            entityType.Relational().TableName = tableName.Substring(TableNamePrefix.Length);
    }
}
```

**Update (EF Core 3.0+):** Use `entityType.GetTableName()` and `entityType.SetTableName(...)` extension methods.

Comment: Thanks so much, that did exactly what I want. Do you for see any issue doing this could cause?

Comment: No. It's a standard way of specifying different table name for an entity and has nothing in common with identity tables - from the EF point of view they are entities like any others. We are just changing the default table names. I guess they choose the default prefix just to easily distinguish them from your tables when looking in the database.